# Query and {JSON]

Tags: json, google-bigquery

#### While using BigQuery's Console, we were instructed to input some data.

#### The following example was used for guidance

```
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
```

Afterward, I ran the query as instructed and removed the LIMIT clause.

The [JSON] results produced this information ...

```
[{
    "tripduration": "2083",
    "starttime": "2016-04-18T13:02:24",
    "stoptime": "2016-04-18T13:37:08",
    "start_station_id": "417",
    "start_station_name": "Barclay St \\u0026 Church St",
    "start_station_latitude": "40.71291224",
    "start_station_longitude": "-74.01020234",
    "end_station_id": "309",
    "end_station_name": "Murray St \\u0026 West St",
    "end_station_latitude": "40.7149787",
    "end_station_longitude": "-74.013012",
    "bikeid": "23641",
    "usertype": "Subscriber",
    "birth_year": "1945",
    "gender": "male",
    "customer_plan": ""
},]
```

Some of the results were deleted (TRIM).

I attempted to locate the `longest ride` on the citibikes and the `shortest ride` as well. (`In terms of distance`).

I didn't calibrate the information correctly. Therefore, I didn't receive any response for this calculation.

[JSON] is a query result-based language, will it create the same response each time it's used for public datasets?